# How to add address to .CC field?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have working code where I would like to add CC field with preexisting email id's.

Tried all ways around, but not able to crack the code

```vb
Sub Reply_Scripting()

    Dim origEmail As MailItem

    Dim replyEmail As MailItem

    Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem

    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)

    Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Test.oft")

    replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody

    replyEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add

```
replyEmail.CC = "Om3r@email.com"
```

Example

```
Sub Reply_Scripting()
    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim replyEmail As MailItem
    Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem

    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
    Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Test.oft")

    replyEmail.CC = "Om3r@email.com"

    replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.reply.HTMLBody
    replyEmail.display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's same as what you did for your body.

```
Sub Reply_Scripting()
Dim origEmail As MailItem

Dim replyEmail As MailItem

Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem

Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)

Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\ashu\Desktop\test.oft")

'/ Add new CC addresses along with existing addresses.
replyEmail.CC = origEmail.CC & ";" & "a@b.com;c@d.com"


replyEmail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody

replyEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: looks like we posted at same time.. :-)

Comment: also is there a way to alter original subject line in the way we want while replying. Also can we call some of the text from original email to my template. For eg. I have a field call client and my original email also have client can i get the same name to my template file. I know i am asking too many question..